# Identifying the nature of field present in a region, whether electric or magnetic

Tags: electromagnetism

I had this question in my 12th class book and it was an MCQ:

How can you use the motion of a charged particle to distinguish between the electric or magnetic field present in the region by firing the charge

Options were:
1.) Perpendicular to the field
2.) Parallel to the field
3.) From opposite directions
4.) With different sppeds

In the answers section, option 3.) was given as the answer. And I understand very well why it can be an answer to this question (So please don't fill up the page explaining me that).

My question here is, why (along with 3) options 1.) and 2.) cannot be the answers. Option 1.) will make the charge move in a circular path (perpendicular to the direction of the magnetic field and that of the original velocity), in case the field is magnetic and in a parabolic path (curving parallel to the direction of the field) in case of electric field.

Option 2.) will let the charge flow undisturbed in case of a magnetic field and will either accelerate or decelerate it in case of an electric field.

Then why only 3rd option is correct?

Answer (score 0):

With **all 4 options you can distinguish** between E- and B-Field.
Number 4 reveals the field if the charged particle has speed zero in the 1st test. Acceleration means E-field present. If no acceleration, then only a B-Field can be present, but doesn't have to be, so a speed > 0 as 2nd test will reveal a B-Field, unless the B-Field is homogenous and by chance parallel to the speed-vector. To be sure in case of no deflection, do a 3rd test with motion in a different direction.

But **many details are not clear** to fully answer this question, e.g.

1. Only static fields are involved or changing ones, frequency range?
2. Which methods are allowed to check the motion of the particle?
3. Full tracing or only sampling at some time and /or space coordinates? 
   What is the sampling frequency related to the maximum field frequencies (in case of non-static fields)?
4. Relativistic effects to be taken into account?
5. "... present in the region by firing the charge." How big is that region in relation to possible maximum sampling frequencies and maximum charge speeds?
6. "...to distinguish between the electric or magnetic field present..." Is this a logical EX-OR, i.e. either an E-Field without B-Field or vice-versa is present? Or is a mixture allowed? The title of the question sounds like it is an EX-OR, but this is not exactly stated.
7. Are the (static) fields homogenous in space?

If only answer 3 is correct, one must conclude that **there are some important details missing** in the question.